# SQL Table Self Join (or Union?) Trouble

Tags: sql, join, union

How would I get these results from this table? I'm not entirely sure if its a union or join I should be doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Table**

```
WorkOrderID   Activity      PlannedDuration    ActualDuration
11            Activity 1    4                  3.5
11            Activity 2    4                  3.6
11            Activity 3    4                  5
11            Activity 4    8                  7.2
11            Activity 5    6                  6
22            Activity 1    4                  3.5
22            Activity 2    4                  4
22            Activity 3    4                  3.9
22            Activity 4    8                  12
22            Activity 6    3                  3
```

**Results**

```
Activity        ActualDuration11    ActualDuration22 
Activity 1      3.5                 3.5 
Activity 2      3.6                 4 
Activity 3      5                   3.9 
Activity 4      7.2                 12
```

Comment: Using a pivot maybe?

Comment: I was thinking a Group By with a Case Statement to determine the appropriate column. Are there only 11 and 22 for `WorkOrderID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish this by joining two `SELECT` statements from the same table an joining them. The query could look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT Activity, PlannedDuration, ActualDuration as ActualDuration11
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
    WHERE WorkOrderID = 11) t1
JOIN
    (SELECT Activity, PlannedDuration, ActualDuration as ActualDuration22
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
    WHERE WorkOrderID = 22) t2
        ON t1.Activity = t2.Activity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select foo.Activity, foo.ActualDuration as ActualDuration11, foobar.ActualDuration as ActualDuration22 
from (select Activity, ActualDuration from TABLENAME where WorkOrderID = 11) as foo 
join (Select Activity, ActualDuration from TABLENAME where WorkOrderID = 22) as foobar on (foo.Activity = foobar.Activity);
```

It uses join. You may need to tweak it (adding a group by, etc...) to make it work for your actual database, but this should be a good framework.

In my test case, the query above returned the following :

```
  Activity  | ActualDuration11 | ActualDuration12 
------------+------------------+-----------------
 Activity 1 |   3.5            |   3.5
 Activity 2 |   3.6            |   4
 Activity 3 |   5              |   3.9
(3 rows)
```

Hope it helps!